# CSS: Making page scroll with length of image

Tags: css

As I'm very, very new to CSS, I'm not certain if this is possible (and apologies if it's not), but I want to create a certain effect with a background image.

I already know of two methods of background attachments for the image - fixed, where the image remains in place on the screen no matter the scroll, and free, where the image scrolls in and out of sight normally, attached to the page. I'm looking for a sort of compromise between the two, in which the page scrolls down, and the image also scrolls, but only a small amount proportional to the page.

In essence, I want the scroll to work with percentages, not absolute values. In "scroll," scrolling 50 pixels down the page will scroll the image 50 pixels up. I want it that scrolling 50% of the way down the page will scroll to 50% down the image, regardless of how many actual pixels have been traversed. At the top of the page, we can see the top of the image. At the bottom of the page, we can see the bottom.

Is there a way to do this with CSS, or will I have to resort to other things?

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Fair enough. Guess I'll go study up on my Javascript then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something that is called "parallax" scrolling. This is possible with pure CSS when working with transform-style: preserve-3d; (have a look at this [article](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/)), but to get this work on all browsers you may want to use a javascript solution.